# radical of I is the entire ring R implies I=R?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone prove that:
radical of I (ideal) is the entire ring R implies I=R?
The ring has a unit and commutative.
Thanks...

Comment: Do you require the rings to have a unit?

Comment: What if $R=2\mathbb Z$ and $I=4\mathbb Z$? In case $R$ has a unit, what can you conclude from $1^n\in I$?

Comment: thanks for the comments, I edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $rad(I)=R$ then $1 \in rad(I)$. Since $1$ is idempotent, this implies $1 \in I$. Therefore $I=R$.

Comment: too easy it was. Why am I always thinking complicated. Intuition is abstract algebra doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @cruvadom Intuition comes after hard work, not the other way around ;)